# @babel\runtime\ not found in angular 13

Tags: angular, webpack, lerna

I have a lerna monorepo which contain an angular 13 project, I am getting following errors on building angular project

```
./src/app/app.component.ts:1:0-169 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Source\extension\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\defineProperty.js' in 'D:\Source\extension\packages\addons\src\app'

./src/app/app.component.ts:2:0-169 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Source\extension\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\classCallCheck.js' in 'D:\Source\extension\packages\addons\src\app'

./src/app/app.component.ts:3:0-163 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Source\extension\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm\createClass.js' in 'D:\Source\extension\packages\addons\src\app'

./src/app/app.component.ts:4:0-163 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Source\extension\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@babel\runtime\regenerator\index.js' in 'D:\Source\extension\packages\addons\src\app'
```

This is package.json for lerna monorepo root

```
"dependencies": {
        "@sentry/browser": "6.8.0",
        "citeproc": "2.4.62",
        "js-base64": "3.6.1",
        "query-string": "7.0.1",
        "whatwg-fetch": "3.6.2"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "15.12.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.0.3",
        "@commitlint/cli": "12.1.4",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "12.1.4",
        "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
        "@types/js-base64": "3.3.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.1",
        "babel-jest": "27.0.6",
        "cross-env": "7.0.3",
        "eslint": "7.29.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
        "husky": "6.0.0",
        "jest": "27.0.6",
        "lerna": "3.22.1",
        "lint-staged": "11.0.0",
        "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
        "prettier": "2.3.2",
        "pretty-quick": "3.1.1",
        "rimraf": "3.0.2",
        "ts-jest": "27.0.3",
        "ts-node": "10.0.0",
        "tsconfig-lint": "0.12.0",
        "typedoc": "0.21.2",
        "typescript": "4.3.4",
        "typings": "2.1.x",
        "webpack": "5.41.1",
        "svelte-jester": "2.1.5",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.7.4"
    },
```

This is package.json of angular 13 project

```
{
    "name": "project-1",
    "version": "0.1.1",   
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "15.12.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/common": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/core": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/forms": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/router": "13.3.0",            
        "@microsoft/office-js": "1.1.70",
        "@ngrx/store": "12.2.0",
        "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "3.15.2",
        "custom-event-polyfill": "1.0.7",
        "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
        "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^4.0.3",
        "office-ui-fabric-core": "11.0.0",
        "office-ui-fabric-js": "1.5.0",
        "rxjs": "7.1.0",
        "uuid": "3.4.0",
        "zone.js": "0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/cli": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "13.3.0",
        "@types/chrome": "0.0.145",         
        "@types/jasmine": "3.7.7",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.9",
        "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.171",
        "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.4",
        "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "4.5.6",
        "@types/office-js": "1.0.187",
        "@types/uuid": "8.3.0",
        "del": "6.0.0",
        "gas-webpack-plugin": "2.2.1",
        "gts": "3.1.0",
        "gulp": "4.0.2",
        "gulp-change": "1.0.2",
        "gulp-rename": "2.0.0",
        "gulp-replace": "1.1.3",
        "gulp-typescript": "6.0.0-alpha.1",
        "jasmine-core": "3.7.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
        "karma": "6.3.4",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.6.0",
        "prettier": "2.3.2",
        "protractor": "7.0.0",
        "ts-loader": "9.2.3",
        "ts-node": "10.0.0",
        "tsconfig-lint": "0.12.0",
        "tslib": "2.3.0",
        "tslint": "6.1.3",
        "typescript": "4.4.2",
        "webpack": "5.41.1",
        "webpack-cli": "4.7.2",
        "webpack-es3-plugin": "^1.5.2"
    },

}
```

so far I have tried deleting yarn lock file, node_modules folders and running yarn install again but it didn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and had to run

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli
```

https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

And everything started working.